# How can I use ViewChildren to get multiple native elements using template variables?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I'm trying to use ViewChildren to get an Array of stacked canvas elements from my template so I can later draw on them like layers in a drawing program.

### drawing.component.html

```
<canvas #canvaslayer style="z-index: 0;"></canvas>
<canvas #canvaslayer style="z-index: 1;"></canvas>
<canvas #canvaslayer style="z-index: 2;"></canvas>
```

### drawing.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-drawing',
  templateUrl: './drawing.component.html',
})

export class DrawingComponent implements OnInit {


  @ViewChildren('canvaslayer') canvasLayers: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ngOnInit() {
     //this.canvasLayers == undefined here and
     //this.canvasLayers[0].nativeElement throws an exception
  }
}
```

When I do this, ViewChildren returns undefined. I think ViewChildren is typically used with angular components instead of native HTML elements, but I would rather not create a new component just to encapsulate canvas.

Comment: How many of them are there?

Comment: What about ngAfterViewInit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returnes `undefined` because you're asking too early. The `ViewChildren` are populated after `ngOnInit` is called and before `ngAfterViewInit`.

```
  ngAfterViewInit () {
     // this.canvasLayers works here
  }
```

Check out [docs on lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

Comment: That worked, thank you. As a side note, the results from ViewChild worked inside of ngOnInit(), any idea why they resolve at different times?